# Node cant find module After install on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, typescript, npm

I installed a node-module with:

```
npm install typescript --save-dev
```

after that I run

```
tsc
```

Which causes windows to tell me, that "tsc" is a unknown command.
I haven't this problem on my private computer, has someone a idea whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try installing typescript globally here

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Comment: Yes this is working, but this can't be THE solution, because i want to have it as devdependency

Comment: Here is a good article on exactly what you are trying to do http://www.sitepoint.com/solve-global-npm-module-dependency-problem/